# convert array syntax to array

Tags: c#, php, arrays

i have result from var_dump (php function) to form of below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => newClass
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => function
        )

    [1] => newClass
        (
            [id] => 8
            [title] => class
        )
)
```

i want to convert this array to equivalent c# array.
i can do it by `for loop` and `substring` and another function to split this string and store it in another array in c#.
but the question is: There's an easier way?

Comment: convert to json in PHP and decode in C#?

Comment: Please show your desired output.

Comment: that is unusual task, as @maximkou mentioned, json is your middle ground. use json_encode in php instead of var_dump

Comment: Why do you need that at all? So you have a string which contains informations about a php array and php types. Now you need to convert that string to a C# array with other C# types which might have the same name(what namespace)? That doesn't make sense.